# Kotlin Type Mismatch for a function return a string

Tags: function, types, kotlin, uuid

```
import java.util.UUID

fun UuidGenerator() {
    val id =  UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return id.replace("-", "")
}
```

^^^ `UuidGenerator.kt`

Just try to build a simple UUI generator function so I can import it into a class and use it to generate random string of 32 characters, but keep getting type mismatch.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify return object `: String`

```
fun UuidGenerator() : String {
   val id =  UUID.randomUUID().toString()
   return id.replace("-", "")
}
```

Comment: @Ezeewei no worries, we all been there :). glad it help you

Comment: Note that if you want to leverage Kotlin's type inference you don't have to specify the return type, and define the function as a one-liner




fun UuidGenerator() = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "")

Comment: @talosdev ah cool! thats interesting! thanks for sharing! Feel free to put it as an answer as well so people can benefit!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, if you want to leverage Kotlin's type inference you and not have to specify the return type, you can define the function as a one-liner

```
fun UuidGenerator() = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

All functions in Kotlin return a value (that's why in Kotlin we call them functions and not methods). If you don't explicitly state a return value `Unit` will be returned implicitly. So your code:

```
fun UuidGenerator() {
    val id =  UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return id.replace("-", "")
}
```

can be rewritten as:

```
fun UuidGenerator(): Unit {
    val id =  UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return id.replace("-", "")
    // ^^^--- oops, won't work
    return Unit
}
```

If you take a look at its source it will make sense:

```
/**
 * The type with only one value: the Unit object.
 * This type corresponds to the `void` type in Java.
 */
public object Unit {
    override fun toString() = "kotlin.Unit"
}
```

This is a clever trick to do away with `void`.

Now what you really want to do is specify that you are returning a `String`:

```
fun UuidGenerator(): String {
    val id =  UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return id.replace("-", "")
}
```